# Remove SwiftUI Form padding

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swiftui

When you use a SwiftUI `Form` it creates padding on the leading edge, which is fine for `Form` input but I would like to add additional content to the Form e.g. an image that takes the entire width of the screen, but because the image is in the `Form`, padding gets applied and the image gets pushed off screen slightly. How can I remove all `Form` padding?

```
struct MyForm: View {
  var body: some View {
    Form {
      Image(uiImage: someImage)
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)

      TextField("Name", text: $name)

      // Other fields
    }
  }
}
```

I know that the underlying view for `Form` is a `UITableView` where I can do things like `UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear` to change the `Form` appearance, but I can't figure out how to remove the leading padding.

I also know I can move the `Image` view outside the `Form` and put everything in a stack, but that creates other issues with scrolling that I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
  Image(uiImage: someImage)
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())        // << this one !!
```

Note: hardcode to `UIScreen.main.bounds.width` is not needed

Comment: Ahh thank you! I was putting the `listRowInsets` modifier on the Form instead of on the child view

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in iOS 15 anymore - `.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())` only makes the item fill the form width (without item's default horizontal padding), but not the screen width. See the screenshot in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72303182/swiftui-can-i-make-one-element-in-form-fill-the-whole-screen-width-without-ho